# Finding a string in multiple folders that are in the same directory

Tags: linux, bash, grep, directory, string

I have a directory A that has multiple folders, and I want to find a string in those folders. How can I do it?

I have tried `grep -rw string *` in A, but it takes a lot of time.

Comment: How do you distinguish directories from folders?

Comment: I mean the directory is the folder where all the other folders are.

Comment: Is your command not working (*"How can I do it?"*) or is the actual question just how to speed up the command (*"but it takes a lot of time"*)?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to speed up `grep`.

- If you have a fixed string like in your example, use `grep -F`.
- Use `-l` or `-m1` to stop reading a file after the first match.

So in your case:

```
grep -Frwl string
```

But dependent on the amount of files, it will still take some time. `grep` needs to open each and every file.